# My solution to $\int \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1}dx$

Tags: integration, solution-verification

**Attempt** So I went with integration by parts, with $u=\ln(x+1)$ and $dv=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$: $$\int \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1}dx$$ $$\frac{-2x}{(x^2+1)^2}\ln(x+1)-2\int \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2(x+1)}dx$$ and then proceeded with partial fractions, I hope I don't need to write them as I checked the partial fractions step with wolfram and it seemed fine: $$\frac{-2x}{(x^2+1)^2}\ln(x+1)-2\int\frac{-\frac14}{x+1} dx -2\int \frac{\frac14 (x-1)}{x^2+1}dx -2\int \frac{\frac12(x+1)}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$$
$$\frac{-2x}{(x^2+1)^2}\ln(x+1)-\frac12 \int\frac{1}{x+1} dx -\frac12\int \frac{x-1}{x^2+1}dx -\int \frac{x+1}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$$
$$\frac{-2x}{(x^2+1)^2}\ln(x+1)-\frac12 \ln|x+1| -\frac12\int \frac{x}{x^2+1}dx +\frac12\int \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx -\int \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}-\int \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$$ then finally let $u=x^2+1$ and for the last integral, I chose $x=\tan\theta$ such that $dx=\sec^2\theta d\theta$
$$\frac{-2x}{(x^2+1)^2}\ln(x+1)-\frac12 \ln|x+1| -\frac12\int \frac{x}{u}\frac{1}{2x}du +\frac12\arctan(x)-\int \frac{x}{u^2}\frac{1}{2x}du-\int \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$$
$$\frac{-2x}{(x^2+1)^2}\ln(x+1)-\frac12 \ln|x+1| -\frac14\int \frac{1}{u}du +\frac12\arctan(x)-\frac12 \int \frac{1}{u^2}du-\int \frac{\sec^2\theta}{(\tan^2(\theta)+1)^2}d\theta$$
$$\frac{-2x}{(x^2+1)^2}\ln(x+1)-\frac12 \ln|x+1| -\frac14\ln|u|du +\frac12\arctan(x)+\frac12 \frac{1}{u}du-\underbrace{\int \frac{1}{\sec^2\theta}d\theta}_{I_0}$$ I will just call that integral $I_0$ for simplicity purposes and as $I_0=\int\cos^2\theta d\theta$ and that is a well known integral, $I_0=\frac14\sin(2\theta)+\frac12\theta$ so yeah, that wrote onto the line above is my solution and would like to know **where** I have **mistakened**, **and please do not post an alternative approach, I already know many since this integral is very well known in Youtube.**

Comment: If $dv=\frac1{1+x^2}dx$, then  $v=\tan^{-1}x$.

Comment: Just wondering is it not that the integral of $\frac{1}{x^2+1}= tan^{-1}{x}+ c? $ Are you not suppose to find this and keep the $ln (x+1)$ constant in your first part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error lies in the first step: using that approach, what you should have done was:$$\int\frac{\log(x+1)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx=\arctan(x)\log(x+1)-\int\frac{\arctan(x)}{x+1}\,\mathrm dx.$$Instead, you have differentiated $\frac1{x^2+1}$.

Comment: oh my, I did differentiate both. Nevermind then